# flash alchemy: passing array of floats

Tags: adobe, swc, alchemy

Doesn't work:

```
             var b:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
             b.writeFloat(-50.000000);
             b.position = 0;


             cpp.processFloat(b,b.bytesAvailable);
```

CPP:

```
static AS3_Val processFloat(void* self, AS3_Val args){
unsigned iTestSize;
AS3_Val sOrigFile = AS3_Undefined();

AS3_ArrayValue( args, "AS3ValType, IntType", &sOrigFile, &iTestSize );

float * sFile = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float) * (iTestSize + 1));

int res = AS3_ByteArray_readBytes(sFile, sOrigFile, iTestSize);

fprintf( stderr, "** processFloat() size: %i sFile: %.03f, res:%i\n", iTestSize, sFile, res );
```

fprintf ouput:
** processFloat size: 4 sFile: 0.000, res:4

What's wrong? How can I pass array of floats to swc from flash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is byte-ordering (more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6318399/89218)).  You need to set the ByteArray to Little Endian:

```
var b:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
b.endian= Endian.LITTLE_ENDIAN;
b.writeFloat(-50.000000);
b.position = 0;

cpp.processFloat(b,b.bytesAvailable);
```

Also, your `iTestSize` is confused.  You pass in `bytesAvailable` but then you multiply it by `sizeof(float)` (and add 1??).

Comment: You're right, b.endian = Endian.LITTLE_ENDIAN has solved the problem.

float * sFile = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float) * (iTestSize + 1));
replaced with
float * sFile = (float *)malloc(sizeof(char) * iTestSize);
with no problems too.
Thank you!